# Put external voucher to paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I do a paypal payment with php via the rest-api-sdk (PayPal-PHP-SDK).

Here a small shortcut how I create the payment:

```
    foreach ($positions as $position) {
        $item   = new Item();
        $item->setName($position->getPosition_id() . " " . $position->getPosition_typ());
        $item->setCurrency($currency);
        $item->setQuantity(1);
        $item->setPrice($position->getItemPrice())
        $item->setTax($position->getMwst_wert()); 
        array_push($itemArray, $item);
    }
    $subtotal       = ($subtotal);
    $itemList->setItems($itemArray);

    $details->setTax($fullTaxes); 
    $details->setSubtotal($subtotal);
    $details->setShipping(0.0);

    $amount->setCurrency($currency);
    $amount->setTotal($total);
    $amount->setDetails($details);    
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setItemList($itemList);
    $transaction->setDescription( "Payment for #".$paymentId );
    $transaction->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());  

    $redirectUrls   = new RedirectUrls();        
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl&success=true")
                    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl&success=false");  
    $payment->setIntent(self::PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $payment->create($apiContext);
```

Now the customer is able to pay a part of the complete payment with a voucher (not a paypal voucher). So before the customer clicks the button on my page to pay with paypal, he puts the voucher-code in.

My Question now, how to say paypal, that a part of the payment has already payed by the voucher?
So that the bill is like:

```
item1:    10.00$
item2:    20.00$
taxes:     5.70$
------------------
total:    35.70$
voucher: -10.00$
------------------
to pay:   25.70$
```

At the moment I add a Item to the Itemlist with a negative value (the value of the voucher) and no taxes.
So that the bill is like:

```
item1:    10.00$
item2:    20.00$
voucher: -10.00$
taxes:     5.70$
-----------------
total:    25.70$
```

Is that the right /only way or is there any other possibility to do that case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the right way to process the voucher. Buyer can see detail item values and voucher in PayPal checkout page.